# Compile time comparison of template parameter

Tags: c++, templates, comparison

I have a requirement that, I should use a specific class if an integer passed as one of the  template parameter is greater than a certain value. Otherwise, I should get a compile time error...

It is something like the following:

```
enum Time { Day, Week, Month };

template<Time t, int length>
class Timer
{
}
```

Now, I have to restrict instantiating `Timer` in such a way that -

`Timer<Day,8>` , `Timer<Day,9>` etc should work, but `length` cannot be less than 8 when used with `Day`.

Similarly, `length` cannot be less than 10 when used with `Week` and so on...

Can someone please help me out with how this can be achieved at compile-time?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3881165/how-do-i-validate-template-parameters-in-compile-time-when-a-templated-class-cont

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Pass the result of `length >= 8` as a `bool` template argument to helper template. Provide specialization for `true` only. Having said that, this sounds like homework, so I'll leave the coding to you.

Cheers & hth.

Comment: Yeap, the real solution is to use `static_assert`, what you describe is a way to implement `static_assert`.

Answer (score 7):

All of the other answers go for metaprogramming to detect the condition, I would on the other hand keep things simple:

```
template<Time t, int length>
class Timer
{
    static_assert( (t == Day && length > 7) 
                 ||(t == Week && length > 10)
                 ||(t == Month && length > 99), "Invalid parameters"
};
```

The compiler will trigger the assertion if the conditions are not met, and it is quite simple to verify by the error message and/or looking at the line.

Using SFINAE tools to disable versions of the type does also achieve the same result: the code will not compile, but at the cost of making the error messages more complex to read: *what does it mean that `Timer<Day,5>` is not a type? surely it is, it is the instantiation of `Timer<Time,int>`!*

EDIT: The above `static_assert` is implemented in C++0x, in compilers without C++0x you can implement `static_assert` as a macro:

```
#define static_assert( cond, name ) typedef char sassert_##name[ (cond)? 1 : -1 ];
```

This simple macro does not accept a string literal as second argument, but rather a single word. Usage would be:

```
static_assert( sizeof(int)==4, InvalidIntegerSize ) )
```

And error messages would require a bit of human parsing, as the compiler will complain (if the condition is not met) that the size of the `sassert_InvalidIntegerSize` is negative.

Comment: You should mention that this is C++0x solution. The OP may not know it.

Comment: @Nawaz: There are different flavors of `static_assert`, some of which are C++0x and some are not. The simplest implementation of `static_assert` is `#define static_assert( cond, name ) typedef char sassert_##name[ (cond)? 1 : -1];`, but of course that would not accept a string literal as second argument, so it would be used as: `static_assert( ..., InvalidParameters )` and the error message would be slightly worse, similar to `size of array 'sassert_InvalidParameters' is negative`. We are currently using a similar macro to that in our code base and the compiler has no support for C++0x.

Comment: If you take this flavor, then the error message isn't that good as your original post said. Now template metaprogramming is as good qw this solution, in terms of "helpful error message".

Comment: @Nawaz: The error message will contain a known character string `sassert_` followed by a descriptive meaning `InvalidParameters` (well, invalid parameters is not *that* descriptive, but `InvalidTimerPeriod` could be). On the other hand with the TMP appoach all you get is a `invalid use of undefined type X` (read the error message in your test). Did you use a forward declaration and forgot to include the appropriate type? Or is the condition incorrect? Why is there a complaint about `rule<false>`? I am not using it anywhere! The static assert will point at the exact line where the check fails.

Comment: The whole concepts proposal and the many complaints about the error messages spit by C++ compilers is exactly that same issue: the error message points at some detail in the implementation that you are not using in your code and it does not even tell you what the underlying problem is. The idea of concepts is that they would produce better error reporting by behaving like an static_assert or required features from the types, rather than an error deeper in templated code, where errors are much harder to interpret by humans.

Answer (score 3):

You can do this:

```
template<bool> 
struct rule;

template<> 
struct rule<true> {};

template<Time Tm, int Len>
struct constraint;

//Rule for Day     
template<int Len>
struct constraint<Day, Len> : rule<(Len>= 8)>
{};

template<Time Tm, int Len>
class Timer : constraint<Tm, Len>
{
   //your code
};
```

Test code:

```
int main() {
        Timer<Day, 7> timer1; //error 
        Timer<Day, 8> timer2; //okay
        return 0;
}
```

Online demos:

- http://www.ideone.com/tSBhG ( `Timer<Day, 7> timer1` : commented )
- http://www.ideone.com/mbN6m ( `Timer<Day, 7> timer1` : not commented )

---

Similarly, you can add rules for `Week` and `Month` as:

```
//Rule for Week
template<int Len>
struct constraint<Week, Len> : rule<(Len>= 10)>
{};

//Rule for Month
template<int Len>
struct constraint<Month, Len> : rule<(Len>= 100)>
{};
```

Answer (score 2):

The idea for this kind of validation is generally to hand off the work to a dedicated helper class, which you specialize for each kind of parameters.

```
template <typename T, size_t V>
class Foo
{
  static_assert(helper<T,V>::value, "Wrong Parameters");
};
```

There are two ways to perform the validation:

```
// Require full specialization
template <typename T, size_t V> struct helper: std::false_type {};

template <>
struct helper<Bar,0>: std::true_type {};

template <>
struct helper<Bar,4>: std::true_type {};


// Property like
template <typename T, size_t V> struct helper: std::false_type {};

template <size_t V>
struct helper<Bar, V>: std::integral_constant<bool, V <= 8> {};
```

Of course, those suppose C++0x facilities. In C++03, you'll have to provide the simple `true_type`, `false_type` and `integral_constant` classes yourself.

Answer (score 0):

```
enum Time { Day, Week, Month };
template<Time T> struct Length;
template<> struct Length<Day> { static const int value = 8 ; };
template<> struct Length<Week> { static const int value = 9; };
template<> struct Length<Month> { static const int value = 10; };

template<bool b> struct Limit;
template<> struct Limit<true> { typedef bool yes; };

#define COMPILE_ASSERT(V) typedef typename Limit<(V)>::yes checked

template<Time t, int length>
class Timer
{
  COMPILE_ASSERT(length >= Length<t>::value);
};
```

See [demo here](http://www.ideone.com/Wrlxo).